# Is there a way to put spaces in a slash command discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot which can get the player count of a game on different platforms. I would like to be able to make it so that there is one command called `/count steam` and it will return the game's player count on steam. I already have it setup to do that but I don't know how to put a space in the slash command. I see other bots have it so it is like this: `/command game <arg>` Here is my current code for the slash command (obviously I have all the other bot stuff):

```
@bot.tree.command(name="count", description = "Gorilla Tag's steam player count")
async def count_steam(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(getSteamPlayers())
```

Whenever I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Gorilla Bot\main.py", line 93, in <module>
    async def count_steam(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  File "C:\Users\Sensor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 887, in decorator
    command = Command(
  File "C:\Users\Sensor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 644, in __init__
    self.name: str = validate_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\Sensor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 191, in validate_name
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: 'count steam' must be between 1-32 characters and contain only lower-case letters, numbers, hyphens, or underscores.
```

I am using the latest version of discord.py. I am also using these for the discord module imports (if it helps):

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [`Group`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.Group) named `count`, containing a [`Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#command) named `steam`. This way you would invoke the desired command with `/count steam`.

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

count_group = app_commands.Group(name="count", description="Count something.")

@count_group.command(name="steam", description="Gorilla Tag's steam player count")
async def count_steam(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(getSteamPlayers())

# Add group in the bot's command tree
bot.tree.add_command(count_group)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore ("_"), so you will take this:

**/count_steam**

Comment: But is there a way to do it without an underscore?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).